# Lubuntu connected no internet w/ethernet

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet, ethernet

Lubuntu 17.04

Dell Wireless 1395 controller 802.11g and 10/100 Ethernet wired plug

When I use firefox, states sever can not be found

connection information everything is filled out

IPv6 set to ignore

```
ping www.google.com -c 5
Name or service not known

ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 657.546/675.081/686.928/9.626 ms
```

Comment: If you put `172.217.17.110` into your browser, does it load Google? Wondering if you have a DNS cache/resolution problem.

Comment: I inputted into firefox and display no server.

Comment: Also ping 172.217.17.110 -c 5. 5 packets transmitted.5 received. 0% packet loss, time 3992ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 835.841/855.232/893.968/20.438 ms